# How to set vertical height in order to prevent overflow on a floated span?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a floated span with some text. I have set the overflow to hidden and the width to a fixed width say 100px.

Now when the text becomes too long it just wraps.

I don't want to set the height to a fixed px because that way if I change the font-size I may forget to update the height and so on.

```html
<span style="float:left;overflow:hidden;width:100px;">Very Long Text</span>
```

Comment: Im not sure you're going to be able to do this without specifying a height.

Comment: i dont have a problem specifying a height i just want it to be in a relative unit.
but not 1em. because it mess up with the line-heigth

Comment: it should display 1 line of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to try something like:

CSS:

```
.floated-element {
    float:left; /* Or right, whatever */
    width:100px;
    white-space:no-wrap; /* Keeps the text to one line */
    text-overflow:ellipsis; /* This will add ... to the end of text that extends beyond 100px */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="floated-element">
    ...
</div>
```

If you really want to use a `<span>` rather than a floated `<div>`, you'll want to set the span's `display` to `inline-block`. This will let you specify the `width` while keeping its other inline attributes.

Comment: i think overflow:ellipsis should overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis; . i mean its working in FF when i changed it to that.

Comment: well you need to add "overflow: hidden;" too.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can't set a `width` to inline elements.
2. declaring width and `overflow:hidden` on a block element auto-expands the element vertically so the text will fit.

some more information on what you trying to achieve would be helpful to provide further help.

edit:

the initial idea of `overflow:hidden` is to hide excessive content (often used in conjunction with fixed dimensions). You might want to rethink, what your'e trying to do (do you really need that overflow?).

Comment: @Karim so you don't need to set `height`, the element will auto-expand so the content can fit in.

Comment: and this my problem that i want only to display 1 line of text and cut the rest, but it just expands to be displayed on several lines

Comment: @Karim Aaaaaaaaah, why didn't you say that in the first place? ;) You could use: `height:1.5em;line-height:1.5em;`

Comment: well the problem is that i dont want to use height:1.5em; because it will be dependading on the line height.
i wanted a method that dont use specifiques.
soomething like 1 or 100% which can applied to all cases.
so that in case i change the line-height i dont need to find and change all the line heights everywhere :)

Comment: @Karim well, thats not possible. % depends on the parent-element, and there is no such thing as "number of text-lines". The only thing you could do is use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and use a global variable for that. I use it, and it is really very comfortable but might be overkill for a small project.

Comment: thanks. i will wait a little maybe there is someone who give me an answer and if not you can edit your answer so i set it as accepcted :)

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution to my problem.
i didn't want to set height to some variable value like for example the value of the line-height  say 1.4em (because it can change with time and so i will need to find and replace all the values in the application).
so the other fix i found is that i can set the "white-space:nowrap;" on the span.
waiting for other answers :)

Comment: embarrassing, that I didn't think of this... :-/

Comment: no problem.
this is actually one of the pluses of having stackoverflow.
i got the idea actually by searching for questions on stackoverflow :)